# Why am i getting a syntax error in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Below is my actionscript code for flash, but im getting an syntax error on line 65, any ideas why? The code is for a game called escape the room, where the player must find objects to move on and open the door. When i run the flash movie it keeps flashing and i cant drag anything, which im meant to be able too because thats what the code is about.

```
stop();

inventorykey_mc.alpha = 0;
inventorypotion_mc.alpha = 0;
inventoryswipecard_mc.alpha = 0;


key_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);
potion_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);
swipecard_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);


var founditems:Number=0;

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(true);
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
}

crate1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate1_mc.buttonMode=true;

crate2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate2_mc.buttonMode=true;

crate3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate3_mc.buttonMode=true;

crate4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
crate4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
crate4_mc.buttonMode=true;

drum1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
drum1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
drum1_mc.buttonMode=true;

drum2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
drum2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
drum2_mc.buttonMode=true;

drum3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
drum3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
drum3_mc.buttonMode=true;

bin1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject); 
bin1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject); 
bin1_mc.buttonMode=true;

function escapeRoom(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

function objectFound(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var inventoryName:String = "inventory" + event.target.name; 
    var inventoryItem:DisplayObject = getChildByName(inventoryName); 
    event.target.alpha = inventoryItem.alpha = 100; 
    founditems ++; 
    event.target.alpha = 0; 
    *if(founditems = = 3){* 
        door_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, escapeRoom);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have `= =` instead of `==`...

Comment: @Marty What does `*if(){*` mean?

Comment: @Zze I suspect that is the OP's way of highlighting the line they're having problems with.

Comment: @Marty oh hahhaha.. i was like >___> what is this black magic!

Comment: haha yea its just highlighting the problem :)

Comment: so... is the problem resolved if you eliminate the space in the = =?